# Setting an Object type to $facet errors specification must be a non-empty object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an object inside of my pipeline that I want to set for a facet but am getting an empty object error.

```
{
    _id: 123,
    "NumLowerCodeRange" : "123", 
    "outputObject" : {
        "1" : [
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "Indicator" : "1.0", 
                    "_id" : 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to be able to take this dataset and set the object to :

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate([{
$facet: "$outputObject"}])
```

But I am getting an error of

> 'the $facet specification must be a non-empty object, but found: $facet: "$outputObject"' .

When I test the object out and hard code it, it works:

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate([{
$set: {test: {$type: "$outputObject"}}},
{
    $facet: {
        "1" : [
            {
                "$project" : {
                    "Indicator" : "1.0", 
                    "_id" : 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}])
```

and I get the results I want:

```
{ 
    "1" : [
        {
            "_id" : 123.0, 
            "Indicator" : "1.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also try and create the object manually - and it works in mongosh as this

```
outputObject =
    {
      "1" : [
        {
            "$project" : {
                "Indicator" : "1.0", 
                "_id" : 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "2" : [
      {
          "$project" : {
              "Indicator" : "2.0", 
              "_id" : 1
          }
      }
  ]
    }

Enterprise rs0 [direct: primary] test> db.test.aggregate([{$facet:facetOutputs}])
[
  {
    '1': [ { _id: 123, Indicator: '1.0' } ],
    '2': [ { _id: 123, Indicator: '2.0' } ]
  }
]
```

Am I missing a comprehension of not being able to set an object in the aggregate pipeline?

Comment: I don't think you can do this (store part of the definition for the `$facet` inside of a document). The closest thing might be a view